# Bootstrap 4 Accordion Cards with margin - no bottom footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used Bootstrap's accordion component, but added space between the cards so it would look like this (the - and + were added by me, not relevant here):

[image]

The bottom border of the cards is missing though. How can that be added?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the bottom border was missing is the following inside bootstrap:

[image]

This makes sense when you use the standard accordion without gaps in between. But in this case, there is a gap between the cards so the bottom border is missing.

Instead of changing bootstrap's code which would the reset anyway with future updates, I just overwrote this particular rule in my case:

```css
.accordion > .card {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd !important!;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

And now it looks like this:

[image]